# How to import PlotlyJS with ECMAScript 6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, plotly.js

I'm trying to implement PlotlyJS ([last version](https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js)) with ES6 modules like this:

index.html

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

main.js

```
import * as Plotly from './plotly.js';
```

But I have this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined at plotly.js"

```
plotly.js:21576 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
at plotly.js:21576
at Object.151 (plotly.js:31122)
at o (plotly.js:7)
at plotly.js:7
at Object.699.../constants/numerical (plotly.js:102912)
at o (plotly.js:7)
at plotly.js:7
at Object.1.../src/lib (plotly.js:10)
at o (plotly.js:7)
at plotly.js:7
```

The problem is in library, I think. Any idea?

[Line of error code in plotly.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctR7M.png)

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am also facing the same issue and struggling with it for the past two days ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug [Native ES6 modules vs. the bundle](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3518)

You have to wait for plotly.js Version 2.0 or fix it according to the opener

> I fixed it by changing line 27724 from }(); to }.apply(self); but this is just a hack :)

Of course, the exact line is a moving target depending on the plotly release you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to implement the change in node_module and use a much more radical approach, leverage the [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) utility.

In package.json scripts, one can use it following command to patch the node_modules

```
"postinstall": "./node_modules/.bin/patch-package"
```

The patches for plotly 1.58.4

```
diff --git a/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-with-meta.js b/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-with-meta.js
index 1aaac5a..cb3ecfe 100644
--- a/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-with-meta.js
+++ b/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-with-meta.js
@@ -35864,7 +35864,7 @@ Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
     return request.responseXML;
   });
   if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) this.d3 = d3, define(d3); else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) module.exports = d3; else this.d3 = d3;
-}();
+}.apply(self);
 },{}],170:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
 module.exports = function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
diff --git a/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.js b/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.js
index 365230c..6268511 100644
--- a/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.js
+++ b/node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly.js
@@ -35864,7 +35864,7 @@ Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
     return request.responseXML;
   });
   if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) this.d3 = d3, define(d3); else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) module.exports = d3; else this.d3 = d3;
-}();
+}.apply(self);
 },{}],170:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
 module.exports = function () {
     for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
```

The patches for d3 3.5.17

```
diff --git a/node_modules/d3/d3.js b/node_modules/d3/d3.js
index aded45c..d5b3cad 100644
--- a/node_modules/d3/d3.js
+++ b/node_modules/d3/d3.js
@@ -9551,4 +9551,4 @@
     return request.responseXML;
   });
   if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) this.d3 = d3, define(d3); else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) module.exports = d3; else this.d3 = d3;
-}();
\ No newline at end of file
+}.apply(self);
```